# get all post ids of a category by category slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get all posts under a category by using its slug name (eg. 'most-popular'). how do I do this?

this is what I have tried, but failed.

```
<?php
                    global $post;
                    $id = array();
                    $i=0;
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => "most-popular", 'post_status' => "publish", 'order'=>"ASC");
                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  
                        setup_postdata($post); 
                        $id[$i]=$post->ID;
                        $i=$i+1;
                    endforeach; 

                    $article1= new Article($id[0]); 
                                            $article2= new Article($id[1]); //and so on.
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have to get the `id` first by calling `get_category_by_slug( $slug )`. So maybe something like this:

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'most-popular' );
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => $category->term_id, 'post_status' =>  "publish", 'order'=>"ASC");
```